# Replacing sub-string of a String with another String

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I have a String

```
String str = (a AND b) OR (c AND d)
```

I tokenise with the help of code below

```
String delims = "AND|OR|NOT|[!&|()]+"; // Regular expression syntax
String newstr = str.replaceAll(delims, " ");
String[] tokens = newstr.trim().split("[ ]+");
```

and get String[] below

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

To each element of the array I add " =1" so it becomes

```
[a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1]
```

NOW I need to replace these values to the initial string making it

```
(a=1 AND b=1) OR (c=1 AND d=1)
```

Can someone help or guide me ? The initial String str is arbitrary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on [@Michael's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926984/1393766) (BIG +1 for him) of searching words containing only lowercase characters and adding `=1` to them :)

```
String addstr = "=1";
String str = "(a AND b) OR (c AND d) ";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group() + addstr);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
```

output

> (a=1 AND b=1) OR (c=1 AND d=1)

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Is it possible to use StringBuilder here?

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
String str = (a AND b) OR (c AND d);
String[] tokened = [a, b, c, d]
String[] edited = [a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1]
```

Simply:

```
for (int i=0; i<tokened.length; i++)
    str.replaceAll(tokened[i], edited[i]);
```

**Edit:**

```
String addstr = "=1";
String str = "(a AND b) OR (c AND d) ";
String delims = "AND|OR|NOT|[!&|() ]+"; // Regular expression syntax
String[] tokens = str.trim().split( delims );
String[] delimiters = str.trim().split( "[a-z]+"); //remove all lower case (these are the characters you wish to edit)

String newstr = "";
for (int i = 0; i < delimiters.length-1; i++)
    newstr += delimiters[i] + tokens[i] + addstr;
newstr += delimiters[delimiters.length-1];
```

OK now the explanation:

```
tokens = [a, b, c, d]
delimiters = [ "(" , " AND " , ") OR (" , " AND " , ") " ]
```

When iterating through delimiters, we take "(" + "a" + "=1".

From there we have **"(a=1"** += " AND " + "b" + "=1".

And on: **"(a=1  AND  b=1"** += ") OR (" + "c" + "=1".

Again : **"(a=1  AND  b=1) OR (c=1"** += " AND " + "d" + "=1"

Finally (outside the `for` loop): **"(a=1  AND  b=1) OR (c=1 AND d=1"** += ")"

There we have: **"(a=1  AND  b=1) OR (c=1 AND d=1)"**

Comment: You could also keep track of the indices where you find all the tokens, and insert the desired string:

Comment: But what in case `str = "(A AND B)"`? You will get `str = "(A=1 A=1ND B=1)"`

Comment: Will accept this comment as soon as I make work of it. How can I track their index tho ? Sorry

Comment: Another quick question, case sensitive?

Comment: Even if it is case sensitive then there are more cases showing that simply replacing is not good solutions for example `"b OR bb"` can give `"b=1 OR b=1b=1"`.

Comment: What I was getting at is the "AND" is all caps, and if all the variables were to be lower case, a regex could account for that. But I re-read and since `str` is arbitrary, we can assume no guarantees on this

Comment: yes the booleans are case sensitive so they will always be OR/AND/NOT

Comment: I can restrict str to be lower case, if there is not better solution ? how could a regex help in that case ? if u could add it to ur answer please

Comment: Let me put something together. It'll take a min.

Comment: When I try it it gives me "(=1 AND a=1) OR (=1 AND =1)" It must be something small because the structure and =1 are fine just the actual alphabets are missing

Comment: Ah, the tokens array is 11 elements long. I am looking into why. (tokens[] = [ " " + "a" + " " + " " + "b"+ ...])

Comment: +1 and [this](http://ideone.com/la6NR) is little improved version of this answer. Hope you will like it.

Answer (score 1):

How long is str allowed to be?  If the answer is "relatively short", you could simply do a "replace all" for every element in the array.  This obviously is not the most performance-friendly solution, so if performance is an issue, a different solution would be desireable.

Comment: I have built the Array ! I just need to put back the replaced elements of array into the initial string. Like I want to put [a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1] into string (a AND B) OR (c AND d) replacing a,b,c,d. do you get my point ?

Comment: yes, I'm saying for every element in the array, do str.replaceAll(tokens[i], tokens[i] + "=1").

Comment: @Pshemo raised a really good point "But what in case str = "(A AND B)"? You will get str = "(A=1 A=1ND B=1)"

Comment: yeah, hadn't thought of that.  Well, if you still wanted to go that route, you could use regex matching to say ONLY A and not "AND" but that seems like it's getting too complicated...

Comment: Can you show it in an example or something ? It has to get complicated because as the initial string is going to be arbitrary, I need to find a generic form

Comment: The regex would probably look something like `"[\s!&|()]?" + token[i] + "[\s!&|()]+"`.